# Sort a list of objects by their distance from a point

Tags: python, scripting, objects

I have a list of objects like this `[bpy.data.objects["Text.002], bpy.data.objects["Text.003], bpy.data.objects["Text.005], bpy.data.objects["Text.007]]`
how can I sort them by their distance from a point like for example `p =(0, 0, 0)`?

I've tried to calculate the distance from two points in the 3d space using the origin and the point coordinates, but then how can I sort the objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways to sort lists in python. Here is one using lambda.

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Vector
# some list of objects (taken from q)
objects = [bpy.data.objects["Text.002"],
           bpy.data.objects["Text.003"],
           bpy.data.objects["Text.005"],
           bpy.data.objects["Text.007"]]
# sort by location from (0, 0, 0)
objects.sort(key=lambda o: o.location.length)
# sort by visual location from (0, 0, 0)
# eg objects moved by constraint / parenting etc.
objects.sort(key=lambda o:
             o.matrix_world.to_translation().length)

v = Vector((1, 2, 3))
# sort by distance from v
objects.sort(key=lambda o:
             (o.matrix_world.to_translation() - v).length)
```